Solving linear differential equation with semigroup
I want to understand the relationship between a linear operator $L$ and the semigroup for the corresponding differential equation
$$ f_t = Lf \,. $$
Consider the differential equation on the domain $(0,1)$,
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t,x) = - f(t,x) + g(t) \, =: Lf(t,x) \,.$$
I want to express the solution explicitly using the semigroup $T(t) = e^{Lt}$.
I tried the integrating factor method: this gives the solution
$$ f(t,x) = e^{-t}\left( \int_0^s e^s g(s) ds + f(0, x) \right)\,.$$
Is that right?
I'm trying to do this with the case $g(t) = \int_0^1 f(t,y)dy$. Then, I don't know how to integrate $\int_0^s e^sg(s)ds$. I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to get
$$ f(t,x) = T(t) f(0) = g(t)(1-e^{-t}) + f(0,x) e^{-t} \,. $$

Three points: 1) As described, the operator $L$ does not appear to be a linear operator. For instance, does $L2f = 2Lf$? 2) The upper bound of integration in your integrating factor solution should be $t$, not $s$. 3) You cannot integrate $\int_0^t e^s g(s) ds$ without knowing what $g$ is.

"Is that right?" Hint: differentiate that "solution".
